# WebBased python script gui or some sort of user interface

Tags: python, user-interface

How is possible to make a python script more user friendly. I mean, not everyone is familiar with shell based use. Instead users prefering click click click and thats all.. Can someone provide some help.. ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are looking for a very simple python desktop UI, I can recommend:**

`tkinter`: Comes out of the box. Ugly but will do: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

`gtk`: gtk based bindings: http://www.pygtk.org/

`Qt`: again bindings: https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro

If your app is small and you don't mind an ugly interface, go for `tkinter`

**If you want a web interface:**

This will depend entirely on whether you wish to learn a framework or simply learn on-the-work

Take a look at:

`Flask`: Really lightweight and easy to use: http://flask.pocoo.org/

`Django`: The de-facto "not a lightweight solution". Includes an ORM, template engine, form validations and more: https://www.djangoproject.com/

There are tons of python web frameworks, but I find these two to be good easy-to-learn, good-for-a-particular-task ones.

If you are really willing to dive into the python world, I'd go for Django. It will take some time, maybe a lot. But it's worth it.